# using two variables in JSON call

Tags: json, global-variables

hey I have two variables I'd like to use in a JSON call, I'm sure this is very simple, but I've got the first one in, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a second one.

the variables are "selected_variable" and "condition" and the JSON I have is:

```
$.getJSON('groundup.json', function (data) {
            $("#hotspot_1").find(".content-spot").find(".hotspot-content p").html(data[selected_variable].[condition].hotspot1.content);    
        });
```

the selected_variable works fine, but condition doesn't and I'm not sure why, I've entered them the same way?

Comment: JSON is a data format, not a language.  $.getJSON() is a jQuery function that fetches JSON data by making an Ajax request.  It sounds like you want to set a breakpoint in Firebug, and look at how "data" is actually structured?

Comment: hmm, I want it to be one call, I just would like to use variables to populate the first two pieces of the drill down into the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not entirely sure i understand the question, but

```
data[selected_variable].[condition].hotspot1.content
```

should probably be

```
data[selected_variable][condition].hotspot1.content
```

(note the removed dot between the `][`)